# Match pattern ending with a certain character in grep

Tags: grep

This is a common problem I encounter when using grep. Say the pattern is `'chr1'` in a third column of a file, when I do the following:

```
grep 'chr1' file
```

How can I avoid getting the results including `chr10, chr11, chr13` etc as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this works:

grep -w 'chr1' file

Comment: That would match `chr1` in any column in the file, not as the 3rd column. See my awk solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested in values in specific columns, you're much better off using awk:

```
awk '$3 == "chr1"' file
```